# how create and save session value after logout

Tags: laravel

i am creating session for some purpose but when user logout the purpose value becomes null but i want to use it after user logout.. the scenario is the session is created by admin and i want use this session for normal user but when admin logout its session also become null..

this is the logout code of laravel

```html
 public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do:

first get all the data you want to keep.

then delete all the session data.

then save the data in to the session.

then logout.

```
 public function logout(Request $request)
 {

 // get the data first for example the user's name
 $name = Auth::user()->name;
 $this->guard()->logout();
 $request->session()->invalidate();

 // save the data into a new session
 session(['name' => $name]);


 return redirect('/');
 }
```

then in your view you get the data like so:

```
@if(session('name'))
  {{ session('name') }}
@endif
```

Comment: can i save session data into the session.? bcz my session data is on another place or controller

Comment: $request->session()->invalidate(); this line of code null all sessions of any type of user and controller or just admin related.?

Comment: It will remove all the session data regarding the current authenticated user. Thats why we set the data into variable before invalidate the session

Comment: but i had tried to save session data into a variable but it did not happen, now i am going with a second approach that is i save a boolean value in database and when it gets true then it perform some action. is it write approach or i have to go with session..?

Comment: it depends if you just need a boolean of just true or false then go for it.

Comment: ok. but for general knowledge which one is more flexible or you can say more faster or good algo approach..?

Comment: It's always better to use the database. and of course the boolean approach is more efficient since you will not need to store more data.